# Generated columns in Postgres using a given pattern

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, alter-table, generated-columns

I need to generate a SQL query which can generate a column that follows a certain pattern

The pattern is stored like this `Hello [Name] [lastname]`

where `name` and `lastname` are both columns on the table.

How do i add a constant string at end, start and indbetween attributes?

and how do distinguish between something being a table column and something just being a string i have added that the column should contain?

My query currently looks like this -  and pattern then take

```
ALTER TABLE IF public.nameRegistration
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS generated_colum 
ADD COLUMN generated_colum TEXT generated ALWAYS as (|Pattern|) stored;
```

and pattern is just `Hello Name lastname`

Comment: How do you "generate the query" - can you show the code? Is the pattern stored in the database itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just do string concatenation:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN 
    generated_colum TEXT generated ALWAYS 
    as ('Hello ' || name || ' ' || lastname) stored;
```

As commented by a_horse_with_no_name, in case any of the two column may be `null` you can use `concat_ws()`:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN 
    generated_colum TEXT generated ALWAYS 
    as (concat_ws(' ', 'Hello', name, lastname)) stored;
```

Comment: If you want to properly deal with NULL values, `concat_ws(' ', 'Hello', name, lastname)` might be better